# How can i change textinput border color after switching to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I want to change the textinput border color when it's selected , here is my code :

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView, TextInput, Alert } from 'react-native';

export default class InputOTPScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {

            pin1: "",
            pin2: "",
            pin3: "",
            pin4: "",
        }
    }
    


        
    render() {
        const { pin1, pin2, pin3, pin4 } = this.state
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 0.6, justifyContent: 'space-evenly', flexDirection:'row' }}>
                <TextInput
                    maxLength={1}
                    keyboardType='numeric'
                    ref={"pin1ref"}

                    style={styles.Input}
                    onChangeText={(pin1) => {
                        this.setState({ pin1: pin1 })
                        if (pin1 != "") {
                            this.refs.pin2ref.focus()                           
                        }
                    }}
                    value={pin1}

                />

                <TextInput
                    maxLength={1}
                    keyboardType='numeric'
                    ref={"pin2ref"}

                    style={styles.Input}
                    onChangeText={(pin2) => {
                        this.setState({ pin2: pin2 })
                        if (pin2 != "") {
                            this.refs.pin3ref.focus()
                        }
                    }}
                    value={pin2}
                />
                <TextInput
                    maxLength={1}
                    keyboardType='numeric'
                    ref={"pin3ref"}
                    onChangeText={(pin3) => {
                        this.setState({ pin3: pin3 })
                        if (pin3 != "") {
                            this.refs.pin4ref.focus()
                        }
                    }}
                    value={pin3}
                    style={styles.Input}

                />
                <TextInput
                    maxLength={1}
                    keyboardType='numeric'
                    ref={"pin4ref"}
                    onChangeText={(pin4) => this.setState({ pin4: pin4 })}
                    value={pin4}
                    style={styles.Input}
                />
            </View>
            );

}

}
```

when the textinput is filled it moves to the other one i want to change the selected textinput border color
is there any solution ?
Thanks in advance!

[enter image description here]and this is the resuts [1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMr47.png

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the React Native documentation, you might be able to use the onBlur property to call a function that performs the action.

Here's a reference to the doc: https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onblur

Answer (score 0):

you can easily give conditional(ternary) operator in your style TextInput, for example: `<TextInput ... style={{ borderColor: item.code == this.state.productCode ? 'blue' : 'gray' }} />`